# Xcode 6 enterprise distribution not working

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, ad-hoc-distribution

I am using my company provided enterprise distribution profile (I donot have the userid/password to create the distribution profile) to distribute application. Recently I have upgraded from xcode 5.1 to 6. Since then I am unable to export ipa file. When I chose "Save for Enterprise Distribution" > Next it gives error "You need to add an Apple ID account that is enrolled in the iOS developer program". But earlier I used the same process to export application and used to show a window with company provided distribution profile name. Though it deploy application to my iPhone 5s. I have checked `/Library/MobileDevices/Distribution Profile has the provision profile.

Please let me know what am I missing or I have to do to export for enterprise distribution of apps.

Comment: Have you tried adding the Development Team that has the provisioning profile for Enterprise Deployment?

Comment: Didn't get you. Could you please let me know the steps to be followed for this? I have the provisioning profile and certificate. Imported the certificate and as mentioned provisioning profile is still there. Please let me know what needs to be done additionally.

Comment: Xcode 8.2.1 version I´m using and have the same problem.. What I need to do?? :S My account is already enrolled

Comment: @A.Trejo, I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi @WilliamGrand yes my problem it was very simple, I couldn´t save for "Enterprise Distribution" because my membership is "Apple developer program" and to do this, I needed a type membership "Apple Developer Enterprise Program"  https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just hit this same problem. It appears that xcode 6 has added an arbirary restriction on exporting ipas with provisioning profiles that you aren't a team member of. You can get around it by manually exporting and signing using the cli.

http://www.thecave.com/2014/09/16/using-xcodebuild-to-export-a-ipa-from-an-archive/

Comment: I found the similar solution in 3 steps, it really very help full for beginners at  http://datacalculation.blogspot.in/2014/10/making-ad-hoc-build-from-command-line.html

Comment: blogspot link above is more useful and effective than the accepted answers link.

Comment: Well, both are same steps. Blogspot guy just explained it more.

Answer (score 12):

I got the same issue and found this article which helped me a lot about creating an IPA from command line : http://www.thecave.com/2014/09/16/using-xcodebuild-to-export-a-ipa-from-an-archive/

Since you already have your xcarchive created, only the last part is important :

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $projectname.xcarchive -exportPath $projectname -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile “Provisioning Profile Name”
```

As mentioned in the article, the `“Provisioning Profile Name”` parameter is neither the name of the provisioning file nor the UDID, but the name of the provisioning as created in the iOS Dev Center. You can get it from Xcode (it's the name of the profile you used to compile) or using the iPhone Configuration Utility App http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465

Answer (score 1):

With the new Xcode 6 we need to log-in using a apple id which is signed in apple developer program or is a member of the apple developer program. Without developer account id we cannot built ipa with new Xcode. I was able to build the app after log-in to the app id.

Comment: exactly, this is what OP means. But we are looking a way how to solve it without login when .p12 and provision files are available.

Comment: I found an article to solve this issue as an alternate way. I found the it really very help full for beginners too hera at http://datacalculation.blogspot.in/2014/10/making-ad-hoc-build-from-command-line.html