# Xcode Not Reading Parse Framework on External Hard Drive

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have a project that is stored on my desktop. However, there is a framework that I have on my External Hard Drive (parse.framework). Whenever the hard drive is unplugged, or I quit Xcode, and I load Xcode back up, it tells me that the framework is missing. I solved this problem, as I have removed the reference to the framework and re-added it, but I have to do this every time. Is there a way for me to do it once and that's it? Also, I want to export my app as an enterprise export, and the way to do it was answered in this question: [Xcode 6 enterprise distribution not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008319/xcode-6-enterprise-distribution-not-working)
In the comments of the answer, the link that has the answer is http://www.thecave.com/2014/09/16/using-xcodebuild-to-export-a-ipa-from-an-archive/
Unfortunately for me, whenever I attempt to build my app using terminal, I get an error that the framework isn't found. How can I resolve this issue, so that I can build and run without worrying about the Parse framework being on my External Hard Drive?

UPDATE****

As you can see in the comments section below, @YuviGr has told me to import the Parse.framework into my project. I have tried that, but here are the errors that I get:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Volumes/Seagate'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FBackup'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FPlus'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FDrive/My'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FDocuments/Downloads'
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_sqlite3_bind_blob", referenced from:
      -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
      -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int64", referenced from:
      -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_null", referenced from:
      -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_parameter_count", referenced from:
      ___59-[PFSQLiteDatabase executeQueryAsync:withArgumentsInArray:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
      ___57-[PFSQLiteDatabase executeSQLAsync:withArgumentsInArray:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
      -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_clear_bindings", referenced from:
      ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[PFDateFormatter dealloc] in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
      ___30-[PFSQLiteDatabase closeAsync]_block_invoke in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_blob", referenced from:
      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult dataForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_bytes", referenced from:
      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult dataForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_count", referenced from:
      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult columnNameToIndexMap] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
      ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult doubleForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult intForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_int64", referenced from:
      ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult longForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_name", referenced from:
      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult columnNameToIndexMap] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult stringForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_type", referenced from:
      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult objectForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult columnIndexIsNull:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      -[PFSQLiteDatabase _errorWithErrorCode:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      -[PFDateFormatter dealloc] in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
      ___59-[PFSQLiteDatabase executeQueryAsync:withArgumentsInArray:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
      ___57-[PFSQLiteDatabase executeSQLAsync:withArgumentsInArray:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
      -[PFSQLiteStatement close] in Parse(PFSQLiteStatement.o)
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[PFDateFormatter init] in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
      ___29-[PFSQLiteDatabase openAsync]_block_invoke in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      -[PFDateFormatter init] in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
      ___59-[PFSQLiteDatabase executeQueryAsync:withArgumentsInArray:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
      ___57-[PFSQLiteDatabase executeSQLAsync:withArgumentsInArray:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
      ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
      -[PFSQLiteStatement reset] in Parse(PFSQLiteStatement.o)
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
      ___57-[PFSQLiteDatabase executeSQLAsync:withArgumentsInArray:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult next] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I would post images, but apparently I need enough rep to do that.

Comment: Why don't you add the framework to your project's folder?, not just reference it to the external drive

Comment: I tried but after it did, I got even more errors than what I started with

Comment: then you have to figure out the errors, if you want you can add them to the questions and we will sort them one-by-one. But in order for you to solve your problem, and you must solve it if you want to ship your app, you must add the framework to your project.

Comment: ok @YuviGr I will do that. I'll let you know the errors that I get

Comment: you can use http://imgur.com/ to upload images

Comment: did you followed the quick start guide at Parse.com?

Comment: @YuviGr I don't have enough rep to display images, and I did follow the QuickStart guide

Comment: I went though your logs, it seems that parse is not the problem, there are a lot of classes that are not parse related that are causing the problem like: PFSQLiteDatabase, PFDateFormatter, PFSQLiteDatabaseResult... These classes are not part of parse.framework. What other frameworks are you adding

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks

Comment: sweet, what was the problem?

Comment: I needed to include the libsqlite3.framework and bolts.framework. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, with the help of YuviGr, I figured out how to solve this problem. I had to import parse.framework into the project folder, and I needed to have all of the frameworks listed in the Parse QuickStart Guide in the project.