# To save for iOS App Store you need to add an apple id account that is enrolled in the ios developer program for the development team

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ipa

I have been trying to export an .IPA for external client. 
I am using their Provisioning profile and Distribution certificate (via .p12 and their password).

The problem I am facing is that when I try to export it for App Store Deployment or Adhoc Deployment I get the message that : 
**“to save for iOS App Store you need to add an apple id account that is enrolled in the ios developer program for the development team (XXXXXXXXXX)”**

[image: Export .IPA]
Any idea how to export the IPA please. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you log in into Xcode preferences?

Comment: Yes I did. I used my own personal (company) account to login. I get the message saying : Account already exists. This account has already been added.

Comment: Try removing the account, quitting Xcode and adding it again. It sounds like voodoo, but we've seen similar issues that were solved like this.

Comment: Sure, I ll try. Mind you that my account has nothing to do with the external clients account. The message that is blurred points to their Team ID. I am not part of their team or I am not registered as a developer in their Apple Developer portal. So essentially I am using my own Apple ID but exporting it with their provisioning profile and Certificate etc.

Comment: One workaround is to export the IPA from the commandline. This should work much smoothly.

Comment: Hey @ioopl did you find a solution to this? I'll try the command line method.

Comment: This worked for me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008319/xcode-6-enterprise-distribution-not-working